# SQL add table to "From" group, changes answer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that spits out a result:

```
Select Sum(Count(P.Create_Dtime)),
From Player P
Where
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(P.Create_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(P.create_Dtime) Asc
```

Result = 317827

Now,when I change this query to add another table to the from group (i will be adding constraints based on this table later on)...the result spits out a new answer with a sum much larger than the original. For example, the original answer was 317827, and now when I add in the table below, the answer comes out to 6356540, exactly 20x the original answer. There are 20 rows of data in the "Feature_group_xref" table, and the create_dtime column is also in that table. Why are these values multiplying?   I assumed that because i have identified each column (with "P") that it shouldn't be a problem. Any suggestions? If you see below the only thing I added was a new table name:

```
Select Sum(Count(P.Create_Dtime))
From Player P, Feature_group_xref X
Where
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(P.Create_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(P.create_Dtime) Asc
```

Result = 6356540 (There are 20 rows in table "Feature_Group_Xref" and one column is create_dtime. This result is exactly 20x the result in the first query.

**UPDATE - I have this query which gives me the sum of active players within the last 7 days for users created after march 1 2012...

```
Select
sysdate,sum(Count(p.init_dtime))
From Player p
Where
Trunc(p.Init_Dtime) > Trunc(Sysdate) - 7 
And
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(P.Init_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(p.Init_Dtime) Asc
```

I want to take this query and break it down so that the only (init_dtime) values that show up are the ones where group_id = 1,10,20,30, and 40 (Group ids are 1-100). Group ID can be found in the player_source table, and the column "player_id" is located in both the player and player_source table if that helps.

Comment: what you get in the second fragment is the carthesian product of P*X: you get the original result **for every row of X** For the aggregates, this means that the sum/count is multiplied by the number of tuples in X, min/max of course stay the same.

Comment: You should use Joins instead of Cartesian Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two tables in a join query (From Player P, Feature_group_xref X in your case) have no join condition then RDBMS returns their Cartesian Product. That means that each row of one table combines with each row of another.  For example if one table has 3 rows and another table has 3 rows then if you join those two tables without join condition you will get 9 rows.

Comment: Let's say my query spits out a result of 300,000. I want to take this result and break it down even further to only include members where there group_id (another column in a different table) equals certain values. The other column in the different table can be related to the original player table by a column labeled "player_id"...any suggestions on how i get started on that one?

Comment: if Table Players has group_id (it suppose to have unless 1 player can be part of several groups) then you can query players of a particular group by specifying group_id value (where Players.group_id = 30) or (where players.group_id=Feature_group_xref.group_id)

Comment: "Player" doesn't have group ID. "Player_Source" does, and I can match the two tables via the "player_id" column, so would there bet a step id have to take to get the group_id to be a part of this query?

Comment: It's hard to answer such a question not being aware of your ER-model but... then I suppose Player_source has player_id and group_id then you have to join three tables (from Players P, Player_Source Ps, groups g where p.player_id = ps.player_id and ps.group_id = g.group_id)

Comment: thanks for your timely responses..I have **Updated the question above and hope this may be a little simpler so that you can make a suggestion. I will move on to the more difficult ones at a later date but for the purposes of time hopefully this will be easier to answer. Thanks!

Comment: if you want select certain group_id then just use From Players P, Player_Source ps WHERE ps.group_id in (1,10,20,30, 40 ) and p.player_id = ps.player_id

Comment: Awesome, thanks nicholas..before I mark this one as correct and we can all move on, if I want two different results, the one with (1,10,20,30,40) and then the one with all other group ids, what would i change to the query?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be cross join 'ing both tables and hence you are getting this result